# What is the best way of threading values around between different processes in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

Something I have been
thinking about recently, when working with a larger Haskell system, how do you
thread values around between processes in an elegant way?

I have been learning more and more about the relationship between function input and output,
laws like injectivity, surjectivivity, non-injective functions and so on... a realisation I
have had is that most functions in a realworld application, that are processing data from
a business logic point of view are reducing values down to smaller and smaller values until
you effectively end up at some primative type (typically `Bool`) certainly for conditional
style business logic. Or perhaps some other value on a field in your DB that you want to
update.

So lets look at an example of what I might mean. Lets say we have a system with a table of
Users, a table of Products, and maybe a table of Offers. A user can basket a product, and a
product may or may not have an offer you could apply to it. Here I will illustrate a pure
function which determines that an offer is applicable to a product, and another that calculates
a discount for that product:

```
-- lets also assume these types are Persistent data types
data User = User
  { userName :: Text
  , userAge :: Int
  , userHasDiscounts :: Bool
  , userAccountDisabled :: Bool
  }

data Product = Product
  { productName :: Text
  , productCost :: Money
  }

data Offer = Offer
  { offerName :: Text
  , offerDiscount :: Discount
  , offerProduct :: ProductId
  }

productDiscountable :: Entity User -> Entity Product -> Entity Offer -> Bool
productDiscountable (Entity _ user) (Entity productKey _) (Entity _ offer) =
  not (userAccountDisabled user) && userHasDiscounts user && productKey == offerProduct offer

productWithDiscountApplied :: Entity User -> Entity Product -> Entity Offer -> Product
productWithDiscountApplied user (Entity productKey product) offer = product { productCost = discountedCost }
  where
    discountedCost = 
      if not (productDiscountable user (Entity productKey product) offer)
        then productCost product
        else applyDiscount (offerDiscount offer) (productCost product)

applyDiscount :: Discount -> Money -> Money
applyDiscount = undefined
```

This might not be an amazing example, and my question is more about how things scale across a broader system... but note in the example for some functions we are discarding data we receive as input, in
`productDiscountable` we throw away the `Product` and just take the entity key, and throw away
the entity key for `User` and `Offer` just to use the inner values. The same is the case in
`productWithDiscountApplied` where we are taking in some values we do not strictly need. What
if we wanted to calculate a discount with an offer that has not yet been saved to our DB for example?

It seems like the types would make more sense to be as small as they need to be:

```
productDiscountable :: User -> Key Product -> Offer -> Bool
productDiscountable user productKey offer =
  not (userAccountDisabled user) && userHasDiscounts user && productKey == offerProduct offer

productWithDiscountApplied :: User -> Entity Product -> Offer -> Product
productWithDiscountApplied user (Entity productKey product) offer = product { productCost = discountedCost }
  where
    discountedCost =
      if not (productDiscountable user productKey offer)
        then productCost product
        else applyDiscount (offerDiscount offer) (productCost product)
```

This seems much cleaner to me and is typically how I write Haskell currently. The issue I have here
is that in a real world system where all of these peices have to fit together different parts of the
system have different data requirements, and some parts may require reading from lots of different tables.
In the system I work on, we have functions like the above, only with 5/6 different entities in some cases.
In these cases, I sometimes define a larger type to contain all of the different pieces. So something like:

```
data SomeProcessType = SomeProcessType
  { sptUser :: Entity User
  , sptProduct :: Entity Product
  , sptOffer :: Entity Offer
  -- possibly more types contained within this type
  }
```

But much like the reasoning behind narrowing the types with the `Entity` type, there is reason we may want to
narrow this type as well, lets say we want to bundle the arguments for `productDiscountable` into a type like this:

```
data ProductDiscountableParams = ProductDiscountableParams
  { productDiscountableParamsUser :: User
  , productDiscountableParamsProduct :: Key Product
  , productDiscountableParamsOffer :: Offer
  }
```

And you can map from the larger type to this type with some function:

```
productDiscountable $ ProductDiscountableParams 
  { productDiscountableParamsUser = entityVal (sptUser spt)
  , productDiscountableParamsProduct = entityKey (sptProduct spt)
  , productDiscountableParamsOffer = entityVal (sptOffer spt)
  }
```

But then this leads me down a train of thought that `ProductDiscountableParams` should only contain
values that it actually needs to calculate the result, much like the original function didnt need
the keys from the `Entity`, there are also some fields from the types that are not required either.
We dont access `userAge` from user, so why are we passing it? What if `ProductDiscountableParams`
was defined with only the fields that it needs:

```
data ProductDiscountableParams = ProductDiscountableParams
  { productDiscountableParamsUserDisabled :: Bool
  , productDiscountableParamsUserHasDiscounts :: Bool
  , productDiscountableParamsOfferProductKey :: Key Product
  , productDiscountableParamsProductKey :: Key Product
  }

productDiscountable $ ProductDiscountableParams 
  { productDiscountableParamsUserDisabled = userDisabled (entityVal (sptUser spt))
  , productDiscountableParamsUserHasDiscounts = userHasDiscounts (entityVal (sptUser spt))
  , productDiscountableParamsOfferProductKey = offerProduct (entityVal (sptOffer spt))
  , productDiscountableParamsProductKey = entityKey (sptProduct spt)
  }
```

This seems nice from the point of view of the function, in that it is only taking fields that it
requires. It is probably easier to write a test for in that it only needs some basic values. But
it does not seem as safe (two pairs fields with the same types) and is not particularly nice to
look at from the calling site point of view.

I have started to use this approach in some parts of my application but am in two minds about it.

The issue as well with having types like `SomeProcessType` that span multiple business processes
say `SomeOtherProcessType` exists as well, with similar but not identical context, these two types
need a way of getting to `ProductDiscountableParams` in order to call that, if they both need to call
that function for whatever reason.

Another approach I have seen online is people using typeclasses a bit like you would an interface in
an OO language. You might instead define `ProductDiscountableParams` as a typeclass:

```
class ProductDiscountableParams a where
  productDiscountableParamsUserDisabled :: a -> Bool
  productDiscountableParamsUserHasDiscounts :: a -> Bool
  productDiscountableParamsOfferProductKey :: a -> Key Product
  productDiscountableParamsProductKey :: a -> Key Product
```

You could define instances here much in the same way as the mapping described earlier:

```
instance ProductDiscountableParams SomeProcessType where
  productDiscountableParamsUserDisabled = userDisabled . entityVal . sptUser
  productDiscountableParamsUserHasDiscounts = userHasDiscounts . entityVal . sptUser
  productDiscountableParamsOfferProductKey = offerProduct . entityVal . sptOffer
  productDiscountableParamsProductKey = entityKey . sptProduct
```

Which makes it so that the calling site is much cleaner:

```
productDiscountable (spt :: SomeProcessType)
```

What are the best practices to stick to with regards the above? I feel like leaning on always trying to
reduce the type down to its smallest representation is not always the way to go, but I also don't
feel great about passing around the database entities either, and that there should be a nicer way
to model problem input/output.

Comment: Aside: as a matter of style, I find it convenient to either abbreviate record field prefixes, e.g. `productDiscountableParamsUser` → `pdpUser`, or more often of late, encapsulate a type in a module *without* prefixes, then refer to the fields qualified elsewhere, e.g. `module ProductDiscountable (…) where data Params = Params { user :: User, … }` + `import qualified ProductDiscountable as PD` + `params = PD.Params { … }` + `PD.user params`. (This also works well with lenses.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you’ve observed, there’s often a tradeoff in business logic between giving a function a *minimal domain* to enforce correctness, and the convenience of actually *calling* that function on the restricted domain. Haskell record types are a bit unwieldy for this use case because you have to explicitly interoperate between them, and can’t say “I will only use such-and-such fields” in an ad-hoc fashion.

One thing I do in this circumstance is separating the two concerns by having an *implementation* function that takes only the exact information it needs, and a separate *interface* function that accepts a larger type and extracts those fields to pass to the actual logic.

```
productDiscountable :: SomeProcessType -> Bool
productDiscountable spt = productDiscountable u p o
  where
    -- Extract relevant info from larger types.
    u = entityVal (sptUser spt)
    p = entityKey (sptProduct spt)
    o = entityVal (sptOffer spt)

productDiscountable' :: User -> Key Product -> Offer -> Bool
productDiscountable' u p o = …  -- Use restricted types for business logic.
```

And you can still make a separate type like `ProductDiscountableParams` for the restricted fields if you want.

I wouldn’t *generally* reach for typeclasses for this purpose, because all they provide here is overloading rather than laws, but if you want to go down that route because you have several distinct types that fulfill this interface, this is a natural place to use lenses.

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

import Control.Lens (Lens')  -- Use whichever lens library you prefer
import Data.Functor ((<&>))  -- Flipped <$>, convenient for defining lenses

class HasProductDiscountableParams a where
  productDiscountableParams :: Lens' a (User, Key Product, Offer)
  -- or: Lens' a ProductDiscountableParams

instance HasProductDiscountableParams SomeProcessType where

  productDiscountableParams :: Lens' SomeProcessType (User, Key Product, Offer)
  -- ===
  --   :: (Functor f)
  --   => ((User, Key Product, Offer) -> f (User, Key Product, Offer))
  --   -> SomeProcessType -> f SomeProcessType

  productDiscountableParams f
    spt { sptUser = u, sptProduct = p, sptOffer = o }

    -- Extract relevant fields
    = f (u, p, o)

    -- Reconstitute record
    <&> \ (u', p', o') -> spt { sptUser = u { … = u' … }, … }
```

Then you can use `view productDiscountableParams spt` to extract only those portions you’re interested in, or `over` / `set` to update them. (I’ve left some “holes” here because I’m not familiar with Persistent, so I hope it’s clear nevertheless.)

Another option that may be adaptable for your use case is the [higher-kinded data](https://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/higher-kinded-data/) pattern (HKD), where the same record is reused with different internal “wrapper” types, matching on `Identity` to remove wrapping entirely:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity)

type family HKD f a where
  HKD Identity a =   a
  HKD f        a = f a

data SomeProcessTypeF f = SomeProcessTypeF
  { sptUser    :: HKD f User
  , sptProduct :: HKD f Product
  , sptOffer   :: HKD f Offer
  …
  }
```

Then you can instantiate it at different types to recover the wrapped and unwrapped versions:

```
type SomeProcessType = SomeProcessTypeF Entity

type ProductDiscountableParams = SomeProcessTypeF Identity
```

You may need to munge your types into a slightly different shape to make it fit this pattern, or use another type family to handle the conversions.